# How to match any characters without space and don't array usefull things

Tags: php, regex, optimization, preg-match-all, regex-negation

How to search all characters without space and optimize speed of my script by don't adding LTEXT, PUSHBUTTON etc to the array.

My pattern:

```
$pattern = "/^(?!FONT)[^\"]*\"\\K(?!\\s+\")([^\"\\n]+)/m";
```

To be more specific: searching chars without characters must be in this place of code: "(.+)"

Input:

[INPUT](https://regex101.com/r/tW8aV9/13)

Output

```
1) FIND: %s: Plik nie został znaleziony\n
2) Some text
3)  Some text 
4) Lautus Theme
5) Plik ten może być używany przez system operacyjny lub przez\n\
    inną aplikację. Modyfikacja tego pliku może spowodować uszkodzenie twojego\n\
    systemu lub uczynić go mniej funkcjonalnym.\n\n\
    Czy na pewno chcesz otworzyć ten plik?
6) Tak
7) FIND: Wyświetla wszystkie linie danego pliku, zawierające szukany ciąg znaków.\n\n\
  FIND [ /C ] [ /I ] [ /N ] [ /V ] ""ciąg znaków"" [ plik... ]\n\
    /I  Ignoruje wielkość liter
8) FIND: %s: Plik nie został znaleziony\n
```

Comment: Post your expected output along with the specific input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`^(?!FONT|2000|\s*\*)[^"\n]*"\K(?!\s*(?:"|\n))([^"]+)`

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/tW8aV9/14)

Explaining:

`^(?!FONT|2000|\s*\*)   #the line cannot start with: "FONT", "2000" or a comment
[^"\n]*"                #should or not contain keys till '"' or '\n' characters
\K                      #clear previous match to start matching now
(?!\s*(?:"|\n))         #the match cannot be empty or only by spaces
([^"]+)                 #the match must end in a quote '"'`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You very much :) I understanding regular expression more :) Did you look at my edited input in the question? I want to exclude some words (`FONT`), but `(?<!FONT)(?<=")(?!\s+")([^"\n]+)` didn't work :(

Comment: It's strange. In PHP i have `$pattern = $pattern = "/^(?!FONT)[^\"]*\"(?!\s+\")([^\"\n]+)/m";` or `$pattern = '/^(?!FONT)[^"]*"(?!\s+")([^"\n]+)/m';` (it's all for preg_match_all) and in regex101 it's working fine but in PHP it's giving output for FONT (Arial etc)

Comment: I copy PHP code from "code generator" in regex101 and the output is different to regex live site: `FIND: %s: Plik nie został znaleziony`, `, 6, 15, 5`, `Some text`, `Some text` and `Lautus Theme`

Comment: Thanks but I saw the script is getting crashed with multiline with ""sometext"". New input and output added

Comment: @Saibamen. I've updated my answer, but I'm not understanding your expected output number 7. Can you give more details in the question?